# Curl can not connect to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I installed elasticsearch and kibana from archieve files and try to learn them but I have some network / configuration problems
When I run the following command

```
curl --cacert config/certs/http_ca.crt -m 15 -u elastic https://localhost:9200
```

I got following error

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Operation timed out
```

I have just uncommented the following line in elasticsearch.yml

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Becuase otherwise kibana throws the following error and doesn't start

```
Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes.
```

While I start elasticsearch throw some error but they don't prevent starting
[image: Logs]

All I want to fix curl problem and run the following command

```
bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token --scope node
```

It also returns

```
ERROR: Failed to determine the health of the cluster.
```

if I comment out network.hosts, curl can connect elasticsearch and

```
bin/elasticsearch-create-enrollment-token --scope node
```

works. But this time kibana does not work

```
Unable to retrieve version information from Elasticsearch nodes. connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9202
```

Comment: I assume when you do not use `network.hosts`, and the curl request works that your curl request is sent to port `9202` ? The error on Kibana feels likes you are not using the right port

Comment: In my kibana.yml `elasticsearch.hosts: ['https://localhost:9202']` so what should I do this to fix it?

Comment: Why don't you use port `9200` ? Which port `elasticsearch` is listening on ?

Comment: I don't change anything about port. And I think something uses port 9202 and this is my problem

Comment: I mean 9200 so elasticsearch starts with 9202

Comment: If you create an aswer that says port is not correct and fix port or give the url of elasticsearch I will accept your answer cause you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

It feels like you might be hitting the wrong port.

default http port for `Elasticsearch` is `9200` not `9202`.